# Negate a Property in Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am actually working with knockout and want to know if there is a way in which i can inverse the knockout property. I have a function IsArchived and want to create a inverse of that, named NotArchived. But I am having issues with it.

The main issue is that I am not seeing any difference in my output. for example there's total of 2000 account in my system out of which its showing 1500 accounts as archived and 2000 account as non archived. Instead of that it should show only 500 non archived accounts.

```
            <li>
            <label id="isArchived">
                <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isArchived" /><span>Archived</span>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label id="NotArchived">
                <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: NotArchived" /><span>Not Archived</span>
            </label>
        </li
```

JavaScript:

```
   function WorkersViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    var initialized = false;

    self.isArchived = ko.observable(false);
    self.NotArchived = ko.observable(true);

};
   self.navigateToSearch = function(uriArray) {

        if (self.isArchived()) {
            uriArray.push({
                isArchived: true
            });
        }
        if (self.NotArchived()) {
            uriArray.push({
                NotArchived: false
            });
}

    self.runSearch = function() {
        var parameters = {

            IsArchived: self.isArchived() ? true : null,
            NotArchived: self.isArchived() ? false : null,
        };
```

Comment: Isnt one checkbox enough for a bool state

Comment: @Anders: yes you are fully right, but i also agree that there are some situations where just putting in the markup a reference to an observable is easier and shorter.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by using a [computed](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html).

```
function WorkersViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    var initialized = false;

    self.isArchived = ko.observable(false);
    self.NotArchived = ko.computed({
         read: function(){ return !self.isArchived() },
         write : function(value) { self.isArchived(!value); }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending from the evaluation sequence you need, you may use:

1. computed observable
2. subscription

because the solution with a computed observable has been already posted, here is a snippet which uses a subscription:

```
self.isArchived = ko.observable(false);
self.isNotArchived = ko.observable(true);
self.isArchived.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    self.isNotArchived(!newValue);
});
```

Anozher difference is that the computed observable will be evaluated also for the first time when the view model is instantiated, whereby by using the subscription you should provide to both observables the correct initial value.